# SQL Declaring variable

Tags: mysql, sql

I keep getting an error when I try to declare a variable in sql in the command line. I am wondering what am I doing wrong also can please explain it to me I am a simpleton that understands simple things.

Here is the code

```
DECLARE @MYVAR VARCHAR(50) SET @MYVAR = 'TESTING' PRINT @MYVAR;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'DECLARE @MYVAR VARCHAR(50) SET @MYVAR = 'TESTING'
>   PRINT @MYVAR' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are missing the semi-colons in your other statements

```
DECLARE @MYVAR VARCHAR(50);
SET @MYVAR = 'TESTING';
PRINT @MYVAR;
```